# jQueryMobile theming a navbar in a header with a different swatch

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jquerymobile theming, I want the navbars in the header to use a different swatch than the header. According to the examples at the bottom of http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html, it seems that all I need to do is apply the themes to the individual links that serve as navbar items. If you view source on the examples, they look similar to what I have in my code.

Currently, swatch A is applied to the header (where the logo image is), but the navbar is just a standard grey.

```
  <section data-role="page" data-theme="a">
      <header data-role="header">
        <img src="images/mcn-logo-rev.png" id="logo" />
        <img src="images/question-mark-in-circle.png" id="help" class="ui-btn-right" />

        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="mcn-messages" data-theme="b">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="mcn-groups" data-theme="b">Groups</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="mcn-settings" data-theme="b">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-theme="b">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-theme="b">Unread</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-theme="b">Search</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
...
```

Comment: Are you closing your tags properly? Does the "b" theme work elsewhere? Because I just tried your markup and the `navbars` come up in blue (which is the default theme for swatch b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the original markup was ok. I was misunderstanding jQueryMobile. I thought the navbar would pick up the toolbar color, instead it picks up the button color of the swatch you apply. Fixing the theme applied the right color without changing the markup.

Answer (score 1):

The theme attribute should be applied to the list item, not the link within.
Change this code:

```
    <div data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="mcn-messages" data-theme="b">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="mcn-groups" data-theme="b">Groups</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="mcn-settings" data-theme="b">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

<div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-theme="b">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-theme="b">Unread</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-theme="b">Search</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

to this:

```
    <div data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li data-icon="mcn-messages" data-theme="b"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                <li data-icon="mcn-groups" data-theme="b"><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                <li data-icon="mcn-settings" data-theme="b"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

<div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li data-theme="b"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li data-theme="b"><a href="#">Unread</a></li>
            <li data-theme="b"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

You markup of theming the links rather than the list items is not recommended, and may not work in future releases. Here's the source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-themes.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it turns out it was a problem with my theme. I put the answer below and will mark it when I can (2 day limit)

Comment: Actually, what I posted is the correct markup. By applying the data-* attributes to the link rather than the list item, your markup may not be supported in future releases.